# Interaction Button with Oculus quest

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I'm currently developing an app using Unity. I would use the virtual hands to interact with objects/button. I aim to implement a scene where there is an object/button and upon pressing it, another object changes color. I'm wondering how I could achieve this. Any insights or suggestions on how to go about implementing this interaction would be appreciated!

I did some with HTC Vive and Leap motion using Interaction Button (i am looking for something similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple prebuilt toolkits in unity if you want to try that related to buttons and some predefined actions. i guess if you use it and see how it works will help you.

or you can use

```
GameObject buttonPrecolor;
void MyAwesomeColorCreator()
{
    GameObject go = Instantiate(buttonPrecolor);
    var button = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>();
    button.onClick.AddListener(() => FooOnClick());
}
void CuttonOnClick()
{
    Debug.Log("color change");
}
```